# Does $\nabla f\cdot\nu=g\cdot \tau$ Imply $\nabla f\cdot\tau=-g\cdot\nu$?

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

A colleague asked me a question and I got stumped.  Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, and that $\Gamma$ is a closed $C^\infty$ curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Further let $\tau_x$ be a unit tangent at each point $x\in\Gamma$ and let $\nu_x$ be a unit normal.  If we have

$$
\nabla f\cdot\nu_x=g\cdot \tau_x
$$

at each point of $\Gamma$, does that imply that we have

$$
\nabla f\cdot\tau_x=-g\cdot\nu_x?
$$

I did an example with the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.  If we work in polar, a unit normal is $\langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$ and a unit tangent is $\langle\sin\theta,-\cos\theta\rangle$.  The examples I tried all worked out.

What I'd like to say is that, given an $x\in\Gamma$, we can change coordinates to make the curve at $x$ tangent to some circle and then use the above argument. Clearly we can't do this for all $x\in\Gamma$ simultaneously, which sort of bothers me.

What I want to know is, is the above true?  Can my argument be made more rigorous?  If either of those questions turn out negative, what is a counterexample?  Or, what is a valid argument?

Comment: I don't see how the first equation can force $g$ to be anything, since it only involves the tangential component of $g$. (The normal component of $g$ can be anything; given any function $g$ which satisfies the first equation, the function $g+h\nu$ also does so, for any function $h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$.)

Comment: @Hans Lundmark:  Good point.  I will remove the comment from my question.

Comment: OK. But doesn't that settle the question (in the negative), since it means that the right-hand side of the second equation can be anything?

Comment: @Hans Lundmark:  Agreed.  Did you want to post that as an answer, so I can give you credit and close this silly question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $f$, the first equation only determines the tangential component of $g$. The normal component (the right-hand side of the second equation) can be anything, and therefore the second equation need not hold.